# Windowsphone 8.1 System.IO.FileNotFoundException dday.ical

Tags: c#, dll, windows-phone-8.1, dday

I developing a windowsphone 8.1 application and use DDay.iCal libery. I included the libery over nuget.
I like to load a calendar from a Stream. When I Load it i get the following error message:

***An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in DDay.iCal.DLL but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.***

this is my code to load the calendar:

```
var str=GenerateStreamFromString(result);
IICalendarCollection calendars = iCalendar.LoadFromStream(str);
```

Comment: did you include it in the project and set the DLL to copy to local in the project references?

Comment: I installed it over nuget and added an reference to it.

Comment: In the propertys copy to local is also enabeld

Answer (score 1):

The DLL is compiled against .Net 2.0/3.5 and not compatible with Windows Phone.

[image]

This is why you get this error message. Use a library which is compatible to Windows Phone.